# Is it possible to create a fork of a repository that a whole team can use (as opposed to personal fork)?

Tags: git, repository

Our code base is all about integration into this vendor platform that I help support. We are about to go through a major version upgrade, which will take months. However, while we're going through the upgrade testing/remediation, there are still ongoing projects/enhancements for our current version that we're on.

So we had the idea of perhaps, creating a "new version" specific fork, that will synch with the current development branch (which is used for "old version"). However, I'm only aware of how to create personal forks. Is there a way to create a project-based fork that the whole team can use and has a force synch capability?  The only alternative I can think of is to just create a new branch based off of the current one and do manual pulls into it every so often.

Answer (score 0):

## Short version

```
# Display url remote
$ git remote -v
# Add remote
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/ <URLRepoOrigin> 
## - Where upstream is the name of the remote

# Bring changes from the main fork
$ git pull upstream master 
## - Where master is the name of the branch from where we want to bring the changes from the Origin Repository and the name of the remote is upstream

# Upload them to our fork
$ git push origin master 
## - Where master is the name of the branch to which we want to upload the changes of our Fork Repository and the name of the remote is origin
```

---

## Extended version

### Keep your fork synchronized with `upstream` in git

Suppose we have created the fork of a project in [GitHub] (https://github.com/) (*with the name of `https://github.com/MyRepoFork/app.git`*) and we want to keep it updated with the last commits from the original (*with the name of `https://github.com/MyRepoOrigin/app.git`*) and commonly called *upstream*.

### Forkeado repository cloning process

*Next we will proceed from our cloned and forged repository.*

Knowing that from a local working copy you can **connect** and **synchronize** (*track*) against one or more *remote repositories*, remember that when **clone a repository**, by default it is **connected to the repository from where it was cloned** (*in our case the forkeado*):

```
$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/MyRepoFork/app.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/MyRepoFork/app.git (push)
```

Each **`remote repository` has an associated name**. **The source repository**, *from which a working copy was cloned*, **by default** is called `origin`.

Having cloned from our repository, we can **make commits on the fork**.

### Bring update to `MyRepoFork` from`MyRepoOrigin`

#### Adding `remote`

Now, in order to be able to **update the changes made in the original project in our fork **, it is necessary** to add the remote repository** (***connect***) in **our local working copy (MyRepoFork)**.

For this we will connect it with the url and the name that we will give to our remote repository with the command `git remote`:

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/MyRepoOrigin/app.git
```

By convention the name `upstream` is used to name the repository corresponding to the project we have forged:

```
$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/MyRepoFork/app.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/MyRepoFork/app.git (push)
upstream https://github.com/MyRepoOrigin/app.git (fetch)
upstream https://github.com/MyRepoOrigin/app.git (push)
```

In this way `origin` **corresponds to the repository belonging to our fork** (`MyRepoFork`), and `upstream` **corresponds to the repository belonging to the original project** (`MyRepoOrigin`).

#### Updating doing `pull`

Finally, to bring the **latest updates** from `upstream` and thus *keep our fork updated*, run`git pull` on the `upstream` repository and`master` branch (***branch by default, or specify another branch of different development***):

```
$ git pull upstream master
```

#### Going up to our repo

Then it is possible **to upload these changes to our fork** by executing a push:

```
$ git push origin master
```

> #### More Information
>
> For more information, check the following manual pages:
>
> ```
> man git-clone
> man git-remote
> man git-pull
> man git-commit
> man git-push
> ```
>
> #### References
>
> - [Configuring a remote for a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/)
> - [Keeping a fork up to date](https://gist.github.com/CristinaSolana/1885435)